# python gdal import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, gdal

This Python/GDAL is blowing my mind, I followed all the YouTube tutorials and StackOverflow suggestions without success. An attempt to `import gdal from osgeo` still raises a DLL load error, even when all my environment variables are set as indicated. What's wrong?

GDAL paths:

[image: gdal paths]

Relevant Python paths:

[image: relevant python paths]

Both GDAL and Python are accessible via commandline.

But running either this command or `from osgeo import gdal` in the Python window gives:

```
>>> import gdal

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        import gdal
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
        from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
        _gdal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.
```

Comment: long shot but have you got more than one version of python installed?

Comment: Are you using 32-bit Python? If you have 32-bit Python you need a 32-bit library (and vice versa).

Comment: i am using 32 bit. i ensured i have the right things...
i.e GDAL-2.1.3.win32-py2.7.msi, gdal-201-1500-core.msi, for my python build version:[MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

also removed the double entry of python from the paths, it wasnt a double installation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a system we have here running it, all the GDAL variables are under `C:\Program Files\GDAL`  Maybe edit your PATH variable to be this and the two environment variables to be similar (so without (x86)).  Aside from that, it looks to be as it should and I can't even gaurantee this will work.

The two environment variables are:
`C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins` and `C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data`
Good luck!

Comment: Still couldn't work after changing installation directories i cant tell the kind of spell bound on this PC